# Mixed Content, heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku

Hi i was deploying my nodejs App to Heroku, but i got some problems with google fonts 
the error:

[image]

what exactly the prob ? how I can solve it, and thnx

Answer (score 1):

Heroku uses ssl connection to their servers (you can notice it by `https`).

- **What you do** is you load fonts from insecure `http` connection.
- **What needs to be done**: load fonts from https.